# The status of my manuscript changed from Undergoing Initial Checking to Under review but the ED: not assigned?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, publishers, journal-workflow

I submitted a manuscript to one of the weliy journals. The status was “**Undergoing Initial Checking**” on Scholarone system. After 3 days, the status changed to “**Under Review**” along with "**Ed: not assigned**" above it.
It's been a month since this status change. Does this mean that it has been with the editors or has it be sent for peer review by referee? Why does the ed: not assigned but the status is under review?

Is it appropriate to write inquire to the editor about the status of my manuscript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the canonical question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368

Comment: Note that things are easier here if you actually register for the site. And, see the help center: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help